# Why my parameterless ctor fires with Unity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I have a ViewModel called TopMenuViewModel. It has 2 constructors: one without parameters and one with Parameters that should be pushed from Unity.

When I waht to use the viewmodel, injection isn't working and default parameterless ctor is called (not the injected one) so I canot use dependencies. Why and How? :-)

Here is the ViewModel:

```
public class TopMenuViewModel
{
    public int unreadMessagesCount { get; set; }
    public PersonnelAMEntity personnel { get; set; }
    IList<DocumentTypeEntity> quickDocumentTypes { get; set; }

    private readonly IPersonnelAMBusiness _IPersonnelAMBusinessRepo;
    private readonly IDocumentBusiness _IDocumentBusinessRepo;
    private readonly IMessageBusiness _IMessageBusinessRepo;

    [InjectionConstructor]
    public TopMenuViewModel(IPersonnelAMBusiness personnelRepo, IDocumentBusiness documentRepo, IMessageBusiness messageRepo)
    {
        _IPersonnelAMBusinessRepo = personnelRepo;
        _IDocumentBusinessRepo = documentRepo;
        _IMessageBusinessRepo = messageRepo;
    }

    public TopMenuViewModel() {}


    internal void SetMenuFor(int matricule)
    {
        // Get personnel
        this.personnel = _IPersonnelAMBusinessRepo.GetAll(matricule);

        // Get message number
        unreadMessagesCount = _IMessageBusinessRepo.GetUnreadReceivedMessages(this.personnel).Value.Count;

        // Get QuickDocumentTypes
        quickDocumentTypes = _IDocumentBusinessRepo.GetAllQuickDocumentTypes(SessionManager.visibilityUnit).Value;
    }
}
```

Here is how it is called:

```
public ActionResult TopMenu()
{
    TopMenuViewModel model = new TopMenuViewModel();
    model.SetMenuFor(SessionManager.matricule);
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_TopMenu.cshtml", model);
}
```

When I call SetMenuFor, I got a 'System.NullReferenceException' on _IPersonnelAMBusinessRepo.

Here is the UnityConfig (it is read by compiler because I can breakpoint on it (fired thanks to UnityMvcActivator) ) :

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{

    container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    //container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
    container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IPersonnelAMBusiness)));

    // Business Layer DI
    container.RegisterType<IAMLogBusiness, AMLogBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IAuditBusiness, AuditBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<ICockpitStatBusiness, CockpitStatsBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IDistributionListBusiness, DistributionListBusiness>();  // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IEmailBusiness, EmailBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<INatureBusiness, NatureBusiness>();  // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IProfessionBusiness, ProfessionBusiness>();  // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IReportingBusiness, ReportingBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IRequeteBusiness, RequeteBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<ISocieteBusiness, SocieteBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<ITopicBusiness, TopicBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IUserBusiness, UserBusiness>();  // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IUnitBusiness, UnitBusiness>();    // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IDocumentBusiness, DocumentBusiness>();  // No dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IInstallationBusiness, InstallationBusiness>();  // Unit(V) dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IAnomalyBusiness, AnomalyBusiness>();    // Audit(V), Installation(V) dependencies UNIT
    container.RegisterType<IPersonnelAMBusiness, PersonnelAMBusiness>();    // Anomaly(V), profession(V), user(V), audit(V), Unit(V) dependencies
    container.RegisterType<IMessageBusiness, MessageBusiness>();    // Personnel(V), Document(V) Unity(V) dependencies

    // Set resolver
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

}
```

Comment: [Using multiple constructors with DI is anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97)

Comment: generics only allow you to specify a empty constructor `where T:new()` and interfaces don't allow you to define constructor, so there is no way for unity to know you have another constructor, that is why  the preferred declaration is to create with no params then set properties inside curly braces

Comment: I read that Unity chooses a constructor with maximum number of arguments (normally)

Answer (score 1):

When you use following code in controller action:

```
TopMenuViewModel model = new TopMenuViewModel();
```

you don't actually create ViewModel instance via Unity Container. You create it with C# `new` operator calling parameterless constructor.

To make the ViewModel instance created via Unity do the following:

1.Inject instance of ViewModel into your controller constructor:

```
private readonly TopMenuViewModel _viewModel;

public YourController(TopMenuViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewModel));
    }

    _viewModel = viewModel;
}
```

Note that there should be no other constructors in the controller.

2.Remove `TopMenuViewModel` instance creation in `TopMenu()` action and use injected instance saved in `_viewModel` field:

```
public ActionResult TopMenu()
{
    _viewModel.SetMenuFor(SessionManager.matricule);
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_TopMenu.cshtml", _viewModel);
}
```

3.Remove parameterless constructor from `TopMenuViewModel` class. As `NightOwl888` noted, having multiple constructors with DI is an antipattern that should be avoided.

Now when ASP.NET MVC receives request, it will create instance of controller via Unity, because you set `UnityDependencyResolver` as `DependencyResolver`. Unity will resolve instance of `TopMenuViewModel` passed to constructor including all its inner dependencies.